# C comparing strings using ==

Tags: c, assert

I am doing an assignment that asked me to implement a priority queue. It has to pass 19 assertions. I can pass 18/19 assertions but it gets stuck on this one.

```
assert(head->data == "first node");
```

This doesn't make sense to me because why is it using == to compare two strings rather than `strcmp`? How am I supposed to pass this assertion? I'm not allowed to change the code with the assertions. Is this a mistake by the prof or is there something I'm missing.

The struct used to access the data is below.

```
typedef struct node {
    int priority;
    char * data;
    struct node * next;
} Node_t, * Node_ptr_t;
```

Comment: why c and C++ tag, they two different languages, you have to chose one

Comment: is `data` a `std::string`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `data` is an `std::string` then it is using the overloaded `==` operator for that class to compare the string.

Comment: Provide some more code so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: It's a mistake by your professor (assuming you are accurately representing the situation).

Comment: @Mike, I would agree to your hypothesis. It is a mistake. You can't use `==` to check logical equality of the strings.

Comment: @VHS this may be possible with some C compilers/linkers using interning - also indeed if it is the case it would be relying on unspecified behavior (I'v posted that as answer too).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, in your answer you state that `interning` (in C) is not guaranteed. And also, probably only some C run times support it. So with these points in mind, do you still think it is right to do pointer comparison for checking logical string equality?

Comment: @VHS I don't see other solution to this code viewed as code puzzle (ok, ignoring linking alternative `assert` that will always pass, but it is even less likely to work). Indeed relying on pointer comparison for C "strings" should not be done in real code - but definitely good conversation point with teacher/TA.

Comment: `head->data == "first node"` does not compare 2 strings.  It compare 2 pointers.  `head->data` is not an array, nor a string.  It is a pointer.

Comment: To compare 2 strings , code should be `assert(strcmp(head->data, "first node") == 0);`

Answer (score 1):

If this is strictly C such assertion can be satisfied with for most compilers with "interning strings" - reusing pointers to existing constant strings instead of copying value to local array. Most compiler/linker tools will unify all references to same constant. See [How can I do string interning in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634918/how-can-i-do-string-interning-in-c-or-c)

Note that interning is not guaranteed - but I think that is the only shot at the problem. Should be good starting point for discussion about what is "defined"/"undefined"/"unspecified" behavior in C.

---

As originally it was marked C++: if this question is about C++ overloaded `operator ==` - if class of `data` is open for you to modify than you can add `operator ==` that will satisfy that assertion (you can simply always return `true` from it).

Comment: Thank you! The problem was I used strcpy when inserting a new node to the priority queue instead of doing node->data = data.

Comment: @Mike please make sure to carefully read question linked in my answer too - C is not required to actually support this everywhere.

Comment: Plus1 for additional insight on interning in C / C++ in the context of this question.

Comment: The assertion could have been satisfied by the assignment `head->data = "first node"`. No interning is required.

Comment: @DYZ: Yes, interning is required in order for that to work. If interning doesn't happen, then the string literal in that assignment will refer to a unique memory block, different from the string literal in the assertion.